# Combing vectors with one or more similar elements in c++

Tags: c++, vector, int, element

Good day,

I have a logic problem that I'm stuck with.

I have a vector of vectors that contains an N number of integers. Think of it as a jagged array filled with integers.

For example:

```
vector<vector<int>> myVector
```

(lets say, these are the contents of the vector)

```
myVector[0] = {0,1} myVector[1] = {1,2} myVector[2] = {3,4,5}
myVector[3] = {4,5,6} myVector[4] = {7,8}
```

What I want to do is to combine vectors that share the same element. As you can see, `myvector[0]` and `myvector[1]` share the same element value '1', that also becomes true with `myvector` 2 and 3 since they share the same element value '4'. `myVector[4]` stays unchanged since it does not share any values with other vectors

My resulting product should be like this

```
newVector[0]= {0,1,2} newVector[1]= {3,4,5,6} newVector[2]= {7,8}
```

please help :)

Comment: Is each vector sorted?

Comment: Also what should the result be if for example you have three vectors { 0, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 3 } or four vectors { 0, 1 }, { 1, 2 } { 7, 8 }, { 2, 3 }?

Comment: Do you have a problem with understanding the algorithm, or don't you know how to write the algorithm in C++?

Comment: @ vlad each vector is sorted and the resulting vectors would be {0,1,2,3} and {0,1,2,3},{7,8}

Comment: @MikeMB I have a problem in thinking of an algorithm, If I get a pseudocode, I can rewrite it in c++ on my own

Comment: Tony D gave you an algorithm, if that one is not good enough, we need a more detailed desciption of the situation, like: Are the vectors already sorted? Do you always have consecutive numbers? What additional preconditions can we rely on? What are the exact postconditions you want to have satisfied? And as @Tony D mentioned, what have you tried already? It would also be interesting to know what you actually want to achieve, because this sounds a little as if it is either a programming exercise or a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

One obvious and easy way to do this is:

- pre-sort the individual `vector`s if necessary
- iterate `i` through the `vector<vector<int>>`

  - iterator `j` through `i+1`..`end()`
  - use iterators `k` and `l` within the vectors `*i` and `*j`, advancing whichever of `*k` and `*l` has a lesser value until you find a shared value or reach an `end()`: if there was a shared value append `*j` to `*i` and re-sort, otherwise advance `j`

That's probably not the optimal solution performance wise, but you could implement/profile it and let us know if you must have something faster.

Comment: i had a similar idea but I was aiming for performance since the project I am doing requires it. Thanks anyway

Comment: @jeckkcej Which is why it's a good idea to explain what you've already thought of and/or tried in your question - avoid wasting other people's time ;-P.